# true type font is not working on webkit based mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile-webkit

The following @font-face renders on Android chrome, android opera, but doesn't render on any webkit based mobile browser (iOS, android browser, dolphin, opera mini).

According to caniuse.com, ttf fonts are supported by all these browsers except for opera mini.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid_Kufi';
    src:url('fonts/Droid Kufi.woff') format('woff'),
           url('fonts/Droid Kufi.ttf')  format('truetype');

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the problem. The font is Arabic font and mobile webkit has a bug that prevents it from rendering Arabic Webfonts.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92586